# How can code be divided to structure of MVC (except view)for Using JPA(transaction)?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Wanted to divide the development logics structure.
So i divided controller, repository, reposiotryImpl, vo, service.

controller, vo, repository are fine.

But for repositoryImpl and service are difficult divide logics because of transcaction codes in service.

I am using hybernate jpa in sts4.

Blow code is used in service.

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello");             
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
```

Below code is used in Repository interface.

```
public interface LoginRepository {
    List<UserInfo> findUser(String id, String pw);
}
```

Below code is usde in RepositoryImpl.

```
public class LoginRepositoryImpl implements LoginRepository{
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();     

    @Override
    public List<UserInfo> findUser(String id, String pw) {
        userInfo.setId(id);
        userInfo.setPw(pw);

        // it didn't finish the code yet.
        return null;
    }
}
```

So i think emf and em objects can go RepositoryImpl class so they can use that objects for using data CRUD. But problem is tx object seems like have to remain in service class for transaction.

Or emf, em, tx all should stay in Service class?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the service class and its implementation class are generally difficult to separate, so the package structure of the service class and its implementation class is generally as follows

```
**.**.**.service
**.**.**.service.impl
```

, However, in daily development, almost all businesses are implemented in impl. For better extension and maintenance, you cannot put other classes into the impl package, even if it is beneficial to your development, if you do sub-do, your project may not have a way to **be maintained** by others.
This is my understanding, and the developers around me are doing the same.

Comment: I meant emf, em code should be wrote in repositoryImpl class or service class. And if code should be wrote in repositoryImpl class then is that okay to use transaction code in repositoryImpl?

Comment: If I understand correctly, and I observed your code again, you put your LoginRepositoryImpl class, that is, your business class in the implementation class of the class factory or class manager? If it is my understanding, then I personally think this is not feasible, you have to separate this, please don't confuse the business class with your other implementations, and, in the LoginRepositoryImpl class, it is best when you use When it comes to the method, go to initialize your UserInfo.